# Redemption RDOSearches not visible on Session.Stores.DefaultStore

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have an Outlook Addin that perform really big scanning and often cause Outlook crash. I made a lot of searches and find out I should use Redemption instead.
I have download Redemption 5.17, I am trying to make a search folder in Outlook to start with. I follow the doc [here](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosearch.htm)

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.Logon
set Searches = Session.Stores.DefaultStore.Searches
for each Search in Searches
    Debug.Print "-------------"
    Debug.Print Search.Name
    Debug.Print Search.SearchCriteria.AsSQL
next
```

I code this with VS2017 C#. I could not find the properties Searches on Session.Stores.DefaultStore

Anyone could help me on how to make a search folder that copy an existing
SearchCriteria from another search folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in an addin there is no reason to use `RDOSession.Logon` - you already have an Outlook session: set `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` property to `Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT` from OOM.

Secondly, Searches property is exposed by the `RDOStore2` interface (see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosearches.htm) - just cast your `RDOStore` object to `RDOStore2`.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, really appreciate my question can be answered by Outlook MVP

Comment: Would you please take look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926042/redemption-how-to-determine-object-types-in-example-code

Comment: If I use RDOSession in the Addin together with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application. Will my program run different thread then Outlook? My problem is that Outlook crash when the program iterate through all Items. If its running on the same thread I will get the same problem. Should I go way from OOM, make sure not use any object from OOM?

Comment: Redemption will run on the thread where you tell it to run :-) If you want to use RDO on a secondary thread, you can do that easily - save the value of Namespace.MAPIOBJECT in a dedicated variable; on the secondary thread , create a new instance of the RDOSession object and set its MAPIOBJECT property to the value saved on the primary thread. See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#Threads

Comment: I need to rewrite my app to make it stable, crashing Outlook periodically is not an option. If I use RDOSession, do I need to change the code that loop through MAPIFolder to RDOFolder, MailItem to RDOMail, Attachment to RDOAttachment? Can I keep use the OOM objects on second thread together with RDOSession?

Comment: Outlook would not let you use its objects on secondary threads - starting with Outlook 2016, it will raise an exception as soon as it detects access on a secondary thread.