# Redemption how to determine object types in example code

Tags: outlook-redemption

I just start using Redemption and not really sure how to use the Doc.
I using C# VS2017 and Redemption 5.17.

```
RES_CONTENT = 3
FL_SUBSTRING = 1
FL_IGNORECASE = &H10000
PR_SUBJECT = &H0037001E
'create new search folder
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.Logon
set DefaultStore = Session.Stores.DefaultStore
set SearchRootFolder = DefaultStore.SearchRootFolder
set NewSearchFolder = SearchRootFolder.Folders.AddSearchFolder("Test 
Redemption Search Folder")
'set the restriction to search for message with the word "test" in the 
subject line
set Restriction = NewSearchFolder.SearchCriteria.SetKind(RES_CONTENT)
Restriction.ulFuzzyLevel = FL_SUBSTRING or FL_IGNORECASE
Restriction.ulPropTag = PR_SUBJECT
Restriction.lpProp = "test"
'specify that the search should be performed in the Inbox and Sent Items 
folders
```

The about example for creating a search folder. When I try to do the same in C# the line

```
NewSearchFolder.SearchCriteria.SetKind(RES_CONTENT)
```

Return a _Restriction object which do not have properties like ulFuzzyLevel, ulPropTag and lpProp.

Second question is how to create a search folder like in OOM. I don't want to use OOM, because of performance problem. Redemption can be installed on a machine that don't have Outlook.

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            MAPIFolder rootfolder = outlookApplication.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.Store.GetRootFolder();
            string sFolderPath = rootfolder.FolderPath;
            string sScope = "SCOPE ('deep traversal of \"" + sFolderPath + "\"')";
            string sFilter = "\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords\" = 'Danger'";
            Search oSearch = outlookApplication.AdvancedSearch(sScope, sFilter, false, "Danger");
            MAPIFolder oSearchFolder = oSearch.Save("Danger");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NewSearchFolder.SearchCriteria.SetKind` will return a different object (all derived from `Restriction` object) depending on the parameter you pass in - for the `RES_CONTENT` type, you get back `RestrictionContent` object. Just cast the returned value appropriately.

Also keep in mind that Redemption needs to have the MAPI system installed to function properly, which means either Outlook or the standalone version of MAPI must be installed.